# Why Use Rollback() Method in EF Core 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, transactions, ef-core-6.0

What does the Rollback method in EF Core do? If I didn't use Commit, I don't need it anyway. If I used Commit, the transaction has already been completed.

```
using (var context = new AppDbContext())
{
    using (var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            var myObjectOne = new MyObjectOne() { Name = "Book" };
            context.MyObjectOnes.Add(myObjectOne);
            context.SaveChanges();
 
        var myVal = myObjectOne.Id * 3.14;

            var myObjectTwo = new MyObjectTwo() { Name = "Notebook", Price = 100, ReferenceId = myVal };
            context.MyObjectTwos.Add(myObjectTwo);
            context.SaveChanges();
 
            transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            transaction.Rollback();
        }
    }
}
```

What does the RollBack Method do? C# EF Core.

Comment: _If I didn't use Commit, I don't need it anyway._ How did you come to that conclusion? The commit stays pending until you either commit or rollback. A pending commit is a strain on your database resources. You should clean them up.